# Sending emails from Python 3 script with smtp library using a virtual machine in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4

Tags: linux, smtp, python3, suse

I can't send emails from Python 3 script with smtp library using a virtual machine in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4. However, using exactly the same code from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, works just fine. Which makes me think that the problem is system-related and not code-related.

What/where can I look for, in order to solve this issue? I have **no admin rights**

In case that helps someone. The code I'm using is the following:

```
import smtplib

email = "myemail@mycompany.com"
password = "mypassword"
to = ["destination@dest.com"]

# with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp: #<- if using gmail 
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.mycompany.com', 465) as smtp:  

    smtp.login(email, password)

    subject = "testing mail sending"
    body = "the mail itself"

    msg = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, body)

    smtp.sendmail(email, to, msg)
```

When I ran the previous in SUSE machine I get a `TimeoutError: Connection timed out`.

I've tried to add a `print(bool(smtp))` just below the `with` line to confirm if it gets to make a connection, but it never gets executed, which confirm that there was no connection at all.